# Excel SQL - Compare Values

Tags: sql, excel

My first post here and looking for some help on how to compare values in 2 tables and bring back a list of the differences

This is to be done in excel via VBA, I tried a few different ways like Full join and Union but can't get it to run.

Basic Scenario is this:

```
Table A has 2 columns,

Column 1 = ID

Column 2 = Qty
```

Exact same set up in Table B

What i want to do is gather a list where the Qty is different or doesn't appear in either table

e.g.

```
Table A has 
    ID 1
    Qty 3
Table B has
    ID 1
    Qty 2
```

So it would bring back one of the records

Or

```
Table A has ID 5 and Table B doesn't
Table B has ID 7 and Table A doesn't
```

Not sure on the best method to do this, i know i can do it in excel via a formula but trying to accomplish in SQL if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a SQL perspective you will be looking at two different statements:

1. ID and Qty combination are in A, but not B
2. ID and Qty combination are in B, but not A

This will look something like:

1. `SELECT tableA.id, tableA.qty FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id and tableA.qty = tableB.qty WHERE tableB.qty IS NULL`
2. `SELECT tableB.id, tableB.qty FROM tableB LEFT JOIN tableA on tableBid = tableA.id and tableB.qty = tableA.qty WHERE tableA.qty IS NULL`

You can union these two together to get a single statement of mismatched records like so:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableA.qty FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id and tableA.qty = tableB.qty WHERE tableB.qty IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT tableB.id, tableB.qty FROM tableB LEFT JOIN tableA on tableBid = tableA.id and tableB.qty = tableA.qty WHERE tableA.qty IS NULL
```

And you can add a reason to each individual SQL statement so you know why the mismatch happened:

```
SELECT tableA.id,
    tableA.qty, 
    "Item in Table A, but not Table B" as Reason
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.id = tableB.id
        AND tableA.qty = tableB.qty
WHERE tableB.qty IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT tableB.id,
    tableB.qty, 
    "Item in Table B, but not Table A" as Reason
FROM tableB
LEFT JOIN tableA
    ON tableBid = tableA.id
        AND tableB.qty = tableA.qty
WHERE tableA.qty IS NULL
```